# Match print output to a variable using Python

Tags: python-2.7

Newbie here. I would like to know how to match the output of the print function to a variable.

I have a text file with the following contents:

5,pon01.nyc:R1.S1.LT1.PON10.ONT11,Richard
6,pon01.miami:R1.S1.LT1.PON10.ONT12,Judy
9,pon01.denver:R1.S1.LT1.PON10.ONT15,Rachel
14,pon01.houston:R1.S1.LT1.PON10.ONT2,Jeremy
17,pon01.chicago:R1.S1.LT1.PON10.ONT22,Matt

When I run my code, it returns the following as expected:

nyc
miami
denver
houston
chicago

Instead of printing the cities, how can I get it to print the corresponding IP address to each city?

```
import os
import re
import sys


file = open("/home/Scripts/names.txt", "r")

nyc = "10.1.1.1"
miami = "10.1.1.2"
denver = "10.1.1.3"
houston = "10.1.1.4"
chicago = "10.1.1.5"


for line in file:

    name = line.strip()
    values = name.split(",")
    line = values[0]
    node = values[1]
    customer = values[2]

    newnode = re.findall(r"\.(.*?)\:", node)
    print "\n".join(newnode)

file.close()
```

The expected result should be:
10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
10.1.1.3
10.1.1.4
10.1.1.5

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try putting the city/ip pairs into a dictionary with the name as the key:

```
import os, re, sys

ip_dict = {'nyc': "10.1.1.1", 
           'miami': "10.1.1.2", 
           'denver': "10.1.1.3", 
           'houston': "10.1.1.4", 
           'chicago': "10.1.1.5"
}

with open("/home/Scripts/names.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        name = line.strip()
        values = name.split(",")
        line = values[0]
        node = values[1]
        customer = values[2]

        newnode = re.findall(r"\.(.*?)\:", node)
        print "\n".join([ip_dict[x] for x in newnode])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your code, however, resulted in the following error:     print "\n".join(ip_dict[newnode])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Ah, oops! `re.findall` returns a list, which we cannot use to index the dictionary. I've fixed the code now to use a list comprehension that will give you what you want.